# Looking for a cool video manager on ubuntu?

Tags: video, video-player

I am looking for a video manager software that allows me to view video and then destroy them directly (pressing DEL) on the file system without leaving the soft?

Does any one know a software that can help me to achieve that?

Context: I have produced a lot of videos from my videocam, and I need to visualize them and keep only the one that are interresing.
Actually, I read them from VLC and then leave vlc, destroy it when needed and go back to the next video.
This approach is time consuming and boring, that's why I am looking for a video software that is running on ubuntu!

Comment: what operating system are you using? Please edit your question.

Comment: Personally I would do it the other way round. I would have a directory into which videos are initially posted and then move the ones you choose to keep to to a place of permanence leaving the initial directory with the ones you wish to delete en-bloc.

Comment: Mint is off topic here.